# How write to ms word by sample?

Tags: python, docxtpl

I have ms word **sample.docx** like this:

`{{id1}} some text {{name1}} text again {{password1}}`

`{{id2}} some text {{name2}} text again {{password2}}`

`{{id3}} some text {{name3}} text again {{password3}}`

**dict from code**

```py
list_data = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "cat", "password": "123"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "john", "password": "321"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "mike", "password": "555"},
    {"id": "1", "name": "who is this", "password": "342"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "some", "password": "67332"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "horse", "password": "qwerty"},
    {"id": "1", "name": "sone n", "password": "some pass n"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "some n", "password": "some pass n"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "some n", "password": "some pass n"},
]
```

**code**

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
context = {}
doc = DocxTemplate("sample.docx")
for i in range(len(list_data)):
    for data in list_data:
        if i % 3 == 0:
            context['id' + data['id']] = data['id']
            context['name' + data['id']] = data['name']
            context['password' + data['id']] = data['password']
            doc.render(context)
            doc.save(f"{i}_output.docx")
```

**this code get next result:**

0_output.docx:

`1 some text who is this text again 342`

`2 some text some text again 67332`

`3 some text horse text again qwerty`

and

`3_output.docx` have result `0_output.docx`

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

**How get result**

0_output.docx:

`1 some cat who is this text again 123`

`2 some john some text again 321`

`3 some mike some text again 555`

3_output.docx:

`1 some text who is this text again 342`

`2 some text some text again 67332`

`3 some text horse text again qwerty`

etc ....

Comment: which module is `DocxTemplate` from?

Comment: @Lei Yang, from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

Comment: using `for data in list_data:` you always start at the beginning: you should use some index - ie, `for data in list_data[i*3:]`. OR you should group elements in sublists.

Comment: @furas, how fix for working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (Python 3.x):

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

list_data = [
    {"id": "1", "name": "cat", "password": "123"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "john", "password": "321"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "mike", "password": "555"},
    {"id": "1", "name": "who is this", "password": "342"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "some", "password": "67332"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "horse", "password": "qwerty"},
    {"id": "1", "name": "sone n", "password": "some pass n"},
    {"id": "2", "name": "some n", "password": "some pass n"},
    {"id": "3", "name": "some n", "password": "some pass n"},
]

cols = ['id','name','password']

for i in range(len(list_data)):
    if i % 3 ==0:
        doc = DocxTemplate("sample.docx")
        context = {}
        for col in cols:
            context[f'{col}1'] = list_data[i][col]
            context[f'{col}2'] = list_data[i+1][col]
            context[f'{col}3'] = list_data[i+2][col]
        doc.render(context)
        doc.save(f"{i}_output.docx")
```

Comment: instead of `if i % 3 ==0:` you could use `range(0, len(list_data), 3)`

Comment: @furas, IndexError: list index out of range, its - `if i % 3 ==0:` working

Comment: @Юрий it is strage because it works correctly for me. Maybe you used it in wrong place - it has to be `for i in range(0, len(list_data), 3)`.

Comment: @furas is right, the range() function have a ‘step’ param, which can reduce the number of iteration (9 to 3). You can try it out someday.